# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException Can not perform this > action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, fragment, illegalstateexception

I'm looking for a solution to IllegalStateException taking place after

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException Can not perform this
>   action after onSaveInstanceState

and I've come up with the following code. I'm aware of the consequences of commitAllowingStateLoss(). Is it a IllegalStateException-free solution?

```
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    try {
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(this, tag);
        ft.commit();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(this, tag);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not really a solution in my opinion. There is another problem inside your code where you don't do the things right and that's why you hit this error.

Comment: @hardartcore thanks for the feedback. I know the exact purpose but before I refactor the entire part of code, I'm curious if the code above will still throw IllegalStateException